Is pluralism the correct philosophical interpretation of probability?
There are many philosophical interpretations of probability. Is pluralism the correct one? That is, are different interpretations of probability correct for different purposes? In other words, there is no one overarching correct interpretation. Also, what arguments have philosophers given both for and against pluralism? I would like to see some references.

Are you using standard language? I haven't heard pluralism used like that. Rather instead, interpretations of probability. Coin flips are just not like quantum processes like radioactive decay, so it's hard to see how to advocate only one at least of the current interpretations, can cover all cases. You might like to read https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret & clarify your question.

If you wish to be inclusive in your interpretation of probability, you could say that any quantity that obeys the probability calculus can be regarded as a probability. The question is whether it is useful for a given quantity to be treated as a probability.

@CriglCragl it's common in philosophy to use "pluralism" to mean something like "multiple models are true (or true enough) simultaneously"

@CriglCragl "In epistemology, pluralism is the position that there is not one consistent means of approaching truths about the world, but rather many." https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralism_(philosophy)

@TKoL: What I mean is, are there really antipluralists on interpretations of probability? Even a unified approach, will need different regimes, like a hoped for unified field theory is not opposed to different fundamenral forces, just assembles them into a shared picture.

@CriglCragl yes, I believe the historical debate around probabilities has had many non-pluralist participants.

Pluralism is accepted by some philosophers while others hope for a unified theory of probability .
However , fundamentally, probability remains defined as the measure of likelihood or chance that a particular event will occur.

"Probability remains defined as the measure of likelihood or chance that a particular event will occur" - sure, now define "likelihood" and "chance." This is just circular.
